# C# Syntax Knowledge - Abstract Relationships

Tags: c#, .net, c4

This questions requires some previous knowledge about C4Sharp structures and relationships.

I try to create abstract relationships with C4Sharp model, currently I can only specify strings and string variables to define the text+protocol for my structure relations:

```
((It("GSG.container."+getCountryCode()+".DTCConnector") > Global.Structures.Marketplaces.Amazon)["sync", Global.Strings.connection_default_dtc]).AddTags("asume")
```

I cant get my head around the c# syntax where a Relationship object is defined as:

```
Relationship Structure.operator >(Structure a, Structure b)
```

but you can also add strings to label the relationship and their used protocols:

```
Relationship Structure.operator >(Structure a, Structure b, string connection_descrp, string protocol)
```

Which brings me back to the question on how I can convert this:

```
((It("GSG.container."+getCountryCode()+".DTCConnector") > Global.Structures.Marketplaces.Amazon)["sync", Global.Strings.connection_default_dtc]).AddTags("asume")
```

to this:

```
((It("GSG.container."+getCountryCode()+".DTCConnector") > Global.Structures.Marketplaces.Amazon)???Global.Relationships.dtc_to_marketplace??).AddTags("asume")
```